# Perl syntax error with hashes

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm new to Perl and the compiler is giving me a syntax error when I'm trying to use a hash.
This is where the problem is:

```
while (<>){
    @words_in_line = /[a-z](?:[a-z']*[a-z])?/ig;
    foreach $word (@words_in_line){
            %wordcount{$word}++;
    }
}
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
syntax error at ./wordfreq.pl line 11, near "%wordcount{"
syntax error at ./wordfreq.pl line 11, near "++;"
syntax error at ./wordfreq.pl line 13, near "}"
Execution of ./wordfreq.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access a hash value, use the scalar sigil `$`.  Change:

```
        %wordcount{$word}++;
```

to:

```
        $wordcount{$word}++;
```

[perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)